# Limiting an auto sizing text view to n rows of text so padding and cursor position does not randomly change

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextview

I have created a textview for typing messages. I want to limit the number of rows to which the text view's height grows to 5 before the scrolling starts. The math seems to be working as rows grow. But initially, the cursor position is kind of in the center. After I write more than 5 lines of text and delete all of them the cursor is shifted slightly towards the top. But then if I write 4 lines of text and move to 5th line the padding is still incorrect from the top. But once I write the 5th row it again is proper. What am I missing?

Also, it would really help if someone can tell me how to consistently center the cursor so the padding looks clean when rows are added and deleted.

This is the code for my message box:

```
class DiscussionsMessageBox: UIView {
    
    let messageTextView: UITextView
    let sendMessageButton: UIButton
    var maxMessageBoxHeight: CGFloat = 60
    var minMessageBoxHeight: CGFloat = 10
    let maxRowsInMessageBox: CGFloat = 5
    let messageBoxPadding: CGFloat = 5
    var cursorHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         //        countryCollectionView = UITableView()
         //          super.init(coder: aDecoder)
         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        messageTextView = UITextView()
        sendMessageButton = UIButton()
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        messageTextView.delegate = self
        self.addSubview(messageTextView)
        messageTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageTextView.textColor = .white
        let messageTextViewFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        messageTextView.font = messageTextViewFont
        
//        let sizeEstimateLetter = "A"
//        let sizeEstimate = sizeEstimateLetter.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: messageTextViewFont])
//        maxMessageBoxHeight = maxRowsInMessageBox * sizeEstimate.height + 2 * messageBoxPadding
//        minMessageBoxHeight = sizeEstimate.height + 2 * messageBoxPadding
//        print("Letter Height: ", sizeEstimate.height)

        
        cursorHeight = messageTextView.caretRect(for: messageTextView.beginningOfDocument).height
        maxMessageBoxHeight = maxRowsInMessageBox * cursorHeight + 2 * messageBoxPadding
        minMessageBoxHeight = cursorHeight + 2 * messageBoxPadding
        
        messageTextView.clipsToBounds = true
        messageTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        messageTextView.layer.borderColor = accentColor.cgColor
        messageTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        messageTextView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        messageTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        messageTextView.contentInset.left = messageBoxPadding
        messageTextView.contentInset.right = messageBoxPadding
        messageTextView.contentInset.top = messageBoxPadding
        messageTextView.contentInset.bottom = messageBoxPadding
        
        
          
        self.addSubview(sendMessageButton)
        sendMessageButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setButtonBgImage(button: sendMessageButton, bgImage:sendMessageIcon , tintColor: disabledAccentColor)
        sendMessageButton.isEnabled = false
        sendMessageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendMessageButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            messageTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            messageTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            messageTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            messageTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendMessageButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -10),
            messageTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: maxMessageBoxHeight),
//            messageTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: minMessageBoxHeight),

            sendMessageButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            sendMessageButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            sendMessageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            sendMessageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
        ])
                
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(endEditingOnChatViewScroll), name: NSNotification.Name(chatViewTappedNotificationName), object: nil)
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}

extension DiscussionsMessageBox {
    
    func updateSendButton() {
        let isMessageValid = validateTextView(textView: messageTextView)
        sendMessageButton.tintColor = isMessageValid ? accentColor : disabledAccentColor
        sendMessageButton.isEnabled = isMessageValid
    }
    
    @objc func endEditingOnChatViewScroll(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        messageTextView.endEditing(false)
    }
    
    @objc func sendMessageButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let googleUser = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser
        
        if googleUser == nil {
            Toast.show(message: "Login via gmail to send a message.", type: .Failure)
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
            
        } else if validateTextView(textView: messageTextView) {
            
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let userCountryCode = defaults.string(forKey: userLocationCodeKey) ?? "UNK"
            let userCountryEmoji = defaults.string(forKey: userLocationEmojiKey) ?? flag(from: "UNK")
            let profile = googleUser?.profile
            let userEmail = profile?.email ?? "EmailUnknown"
            let userName = profile?.name ?? "UserNameUnknown"
            let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
            
            
            var validatedMessage = messageTextView.text!
            validatedMessage = validatedMessage.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            
            let message = DiscussionMessage(message: validatedMessage, userCountryCode: userCountryCode, userCountryEmoji: userCountryEmoji, userName: userName, userEmailAddress: userEmail, messageTimestamp: timestamp, fcmToken: nil, question: nil, recordingUrl: nil)
            
            do {
                let messageDictionary = try message.dictionary()
                messagesReference.childByAutoId().setValue(messageDictionary)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            
            messageTextView.text = nil
            messageTextView.endEditing(false)
            messageTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
            messageTextView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }
        
    }
}

extension DiscussionsMessageBox: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        updateSendButton()
        
//        print("Content height: ", textView.contentSize.height, "Max message box height: ", maxMessageBoxHeight, "Cursor Height: ", cursorHeight)
        
        if abs(textView.contentSize.height - maxMessageBoxHeight) < cursorHeight || textView.contentSize.height > maxMessageBoxHeight {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        } else {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
            textView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

Initial cursor position:

[image: initial cursor position]

Cursor after writing more than 5 rows of text:

[image: cursor after writing more than 5 rows of text]

Cursor after writing more than 5 rows of text and deleting all of them:

[image: Cursor after writing more than 5 rows of text and deleting all of them]

Top padding before and after writing the 5th line after first deleting more than 5 lines of text:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I integrated your code into mine and found that overriding the `override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize` variable worked perfectly for me.

```
class ChatToolbarView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet private (set) var toolbarView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet private (set) var sendMessageButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var messageTextField: UITextView!
    
    var maxMessageBoxHeight: CGFloat = 100
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
        
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(name, owner: self, options: nil)
        
        self.addSubview(self.toolbarView)
        
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        
        self.toolbarView.frame = self.bounds
        self.toolbarView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        
        // This is required to make the view grow vertically
        self.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight
        
        self.messageTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.messageTextField.delegate = self
        self.messageTextField.isScrollEnabled = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            messageTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: maxMessageBoxHeight)
        ])
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func sendMessageButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if let message = messageTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines),
           message.isEmpty == false {
           // Do whatever with the message
           
            messageTextField.text = ""
            self.textViewDidChange(messageTextField)
        }
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let textSize = self.messageTextField.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: self.messageTextField.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

        if(textSize.height >= maxMessageBoxHeight) {
            return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: .infinity)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: textSize.height)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: UITextViewDelegate
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        
        if (textView.contentSize.height >= maxMessageBoxHeight) {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        } else {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
            textView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me. After the 5th line, I can no longer see the next lines since the cursor does not scroll to it. Can you please show the whole code?

Comment: @ParthTamane Sure, be aware that I am not playing around with cursor padding and I have used storyboards to build my UI... https://codeshare.io/2p3AeX

Comment: Thanks. Could you share the code as an answer? Since you used story board to set up the ui it might not be 100% helpful but can be a good start and reference for others.